# Check for 200 Response of an XMLHTTP 'Stream' with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, http-response-codes

I hope i'm not being docile and missing something simple here but i'm stumped, 
I need to check the response of a HTTP stream from the DI.fm audio streaming servers using Javascript for a chrome extension (Attempting to open a HTTP audio stream with a key is the ONLY 100% way to know if a key is valid for premium audio).

My intent is to validate a listen key (listen_key) and on 403 or 401 error, failover to a different URL. 
The on error is fine and I can handle that using normal on error listeners, but the issue is that I'm using XMLHttp - So when a key is VALID, the stream begins to buffer without limit, Since it is receiving a HTTP stream. I can't find a way to drop out at this point and do a callback saying 200 OK :)

I don't want to have to set a timeout and failover if no errors within that time, as I want to be 100% certain that the error is Unauthorised. The unauthorised fallback will trigger a whole load of status variable changes for other things on the app.

I need to get the response being 200 and drop out as soon as that is confirmed.

Any other error (no data etc.) already falls back to a 3rd function which tries to reload the URL x number of times.

The element i'm getting this 200 status from can also be grabbed by loading the URL in an audio tag and then destroying the element if that's the only way to do it. Just not sure how to go about it best.

Your help is much appreciated :)
Phil.

Comment: http://prem1.di.fm:80/clubdubstep_hi?LISTEN_KEY

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onHeadersReceived

Comment: That'l do nicely. My google-fu failed me finding that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry for not providing a full answer!

Comment: Bah, put ages into writing the question! Heh it's fine,I don't need one, I'm very familiar with deciphering google's API docs, just hadn't come across the chrome.webrequest API before now. Cheers :)

Comment: The work in progress if you're interested: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/differently-imported-for/bnihjdccalbcoienhgcjjlilfdhacdkf?hl=en&gl=GB